# C++ Jeopardy Game Algorithm Design

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, file, sorting

all.

I'd like to write a Jeopardy game that reads the game's questions, answers, categories, and question difficulty levels in from a file, and generates the question board based on the data retrieved from the file. However, I'm stuck on how to make sense of the data in the file.

**Here's what I've got so far:**

My input file is formatted as follows:

```
category
difficulty
question
answer
category
difficulty
question
answer
```

And so on and so forth. There can be any number of categories - the game will choose 6 of them at random. There are 5 difficulty levels (0-4) to represent the "dollar increments" of the original Jeopardy game, which will be indicated by their respective integers (0-4). Next, of course, will be a question and an answer. An example input file could look something like this:

```
Star Trek
0
This is the vessel that explores the galaxy.
What is the Enterprise?
Star Wars
2
These guys always miss.
What are the storm troopers?
```

And so on, and so forth. As you can see, the categories can be presented in any order, as can the difficulty levels. My problem is in designing an algorithm that handles these things.

I've started off by thinking of having my question and answer in a 2D array: The first question would occupy cell [0][0], and the first answer would occupy cell [0][1], the next question would occupy cell [1][0], and the next answer, [1][1], etc. Next, to sort by difficulty, I imagined a 3D array: multiple 2D arrays consisting of question and answer divided by difficulty level. Finally, I figured that by adding one more dimension and making a 4D array, I could sort my difficulty levels by category. Such an array would give me first all of the categories, then all of the difficulty levels per category, then all of the questions and answers with each difficulty level in each category. The array would then be passed on to a different function that actually USES the sorted data.

Sounds like it would work, right? Well. I'm struggling to *make* an algorithm that puts everything into the right place. I've never worked with arrays larger than 2D before, so the concept of a 4D array is fairly difficult for me to understand. I'll paste my current code below for all to read and comment on, and I eagerly await any and all suggestions. If necessary, I *can* change how the file is formatted, but this 4-line organization method is the only method I drempt up.

```
    void oldReadFromFile(std::string dataArray[][5][30][4], int length)
{
    /*****************
     The input file must be formatted as follows:
     Category  //capitalization counts
     Dificulty //as an integer 0-4
     Question
     Answer
     Category //capitalization counts
     Dificulty //as an integer 0-4
     Question
     Answer
     etc.
     *****************/
    std::ifstream inFile;
    std::string category;
    std::string dificulty;
    std::string question;
    std::string answer;
    int numOfQuestions[30][5] = {0};
    int numOfCategories = 0;
    bool alreadyHere;
    inFile.open("JeopardyData.txt");
    //Determine question category
    while (!inFile.eof() && numOfCategories < length) {
        std::getline(inFile, category);
        std::getline(inFile, dificulty);
        std::getline(inFile, question);
        std::getline(inFile, answer);
        //inFile.get();
        alreadyHere = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCategories; i++)
        {
            if (category == dataArray[i][0][0][0])  //If the category already exists...
            {
                alreadyHere = true;
                if (dificulty == "zero" || dificulty == "Zero" || dificulty == "0") //Determine the dificulty
                {
                    dataArray[i][0][numOfQuestions[i][0]][1] = question;
                    dataArray[i][0][numOfQuestions[i][0]][2] = answer;
                    numOfQuestions[i][0]++;
                }
                else if (dificulty == "one" || dificulty == "One" || dificulty == "1")
                {
                    dataArray[i][1][numOfQuestions[i][1]][1] = question;
                    dataArray[i][1][numOfQuestions[i][1]][2] = answer;
                    numOfQuestions[i][1]++;
                }
                else if (dificulty == "two" || dificulty == "Two" || dificulty == "2")
                {
                    dataArray[i][2][numOfQuestions[i][2]][1] = question;
                    dataArray[i][2][numOfQuestions[i][2]][2] = answer;
                    numOfQuestions[i][2]++;
                }
                else if (dificulty == "three" || dificulty == "Three" || dificulty == "3")
                {
                    dataArray[i][3][numOfQuestions[i][3]][1] = question;
                    dataArray[i][3][numOfQuestions[i][3]][2] = answer;
                    numOfQuestions[i][3]++;
                }
                else if (dificulty == "four" || dificulty == "Four" || dificulty == "4")
                {
                    dataArray[i][4][numOfQuestions[i][4]][1] = question;
                    dataArray[i][4][numOfQuestions[i][4]][2] = answer;
                    numOfQuestions[i][4]++;
                }
                else { std::cout << "Bad dificulty detected in input file!\n"; }

            }
        }
        if (!alreadyHere)                       //If the category DOESN'T exist yet, make it.
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                dataArray[numOfCategories][i][0][0] = category;
            }
            if (dificulty == "zero" || dificulty == "Zero" || dificulty == "0") //Determine the dificulty
            {

                dataArray[numOfCategories][0][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][0]][1] = question;
                dataArray[numOfCategories][0][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][0]][2] = answer;
                numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][0]++;
            }
            else if (dificulty == "one" || dificulty == "One" || dificulty == "1")
            {
                dataArray[numOfCategories][1][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][1]][1] = question;
                dataArray[numOfCategories][1][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][1]][2] = answer;
                numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][1]++;
            }
            else if (dificulty == "two" || dificulty == "Two" || dificulty == "2")
            {
                dataArray[numOfCategories][2][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][2]][1] = question;
                dataArray[numOfCategories][2][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][2]][2] = answer;
                numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][2]++;
            }
            else if (dificulty == "three" || dificulty == "Three" || dificulty == "3")
            {
                dataArray[numOfCategories][3][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][3]][1] = question;
                dataArray[numOfCategories][3][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][3]][2] = answer;
                numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][3]++;
            }
            else if (dificulty == "four" || dificulty == "Four" || dificulty == "4")
            {
                dataArray[numOfCategories][4][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][4]][1] = question;
                dataArray[numOfCategories][4][numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][4]][2] = answer;
                numOfQuestions[numOfCategories][4]++;
            }
            else { std::cout << "Bad dificulty detected in input file!\n"; }
            numOfCategories++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use large dimension arrays because it makes it hard to read intent and are error prone. Encapsulate the Question/Answer into a class (`Question`) that stores both and the Category class that has a `vector` (or array since there are only ever 5 questions in a category) of `Question`s

Comment: **TL;DR; Short boildown:** Use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of c-style arrays, that will make life alot easier. **Note** the equivalent of a 2D `float` array is `std::vector<std::vector<float> >`! May be for your needs a use of some `std::map<>` container is even more appropriate to get your 4-dimensional problem domain right.

Comment: you could always cast difficulty to lowercase so then you wouldn't need to check both lower and upper cases and it won't harm if it was a numeral value either, it will also support like ZeRo zErO etc..

Comment: Sadly, I've never heard of classes or vectors. I'll google them and get back to y'all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be over-complicating things, from what I am interpreting from your question. What I would suggest is to create an array as follows:

```
struct Game_Node
{
   string category;
   int difficulty;
   string question;
   string answer;
};

Game_Node jeopardy_board[];
```

or

```
Game_Node jeopardy_board[][];
```

to better simulate a jeopardy board. Then, all you have to do is loop through the file and populate the variables of each element. Simple example:

```
//assumes variables have values and is just for the first node
jeopardy_board[0][0].category = (value goes here);
jeopardy_board[0][0].difficulty = (value goes here);
```

etc.